# Complex alignment in equation

Tags: equations, align, alignment

Why there is no space between the text ("Min/Max", "Subject to") and fm(x) and hk(x). What's wrong?

```
\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
\text{Min/Max}          & f_m (x),                              & m=1,2,...,M; \\
\text{Subject to}       & h_k (x) \geq 0,                       & k=1,2,...,K; \\
                        & g_j (x)=0,                            & j=1,2,...,J; \\
                        & x_i^{(L)} \leq x_i \leq x_i^{(U)},    & i=1,2,...,n.
\end{aligned}
 \right\}
 \qquad 
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Ed.:

Thanks for recommendations. How it should be:

```
\begin{equation}
\left.
\begin{aligned}
&\text{Min/Max}             && f_m (x),                             & m=1,2,...,M; \\
&\text{Subject to}      && h_k (x) \geq 0,                      & k=1,2,...,K; \\
                        &&& g_j (x)=0,                          & j=1,2,...,J; \\
                        &&& x_i^{(L)} \leq x_i \leq x_i^{(U)},  & i=1,2,...,n.
\end{aligned}
 \right\}
 \qquad 
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: Because TeX adds no space between ordinary symbols in math mode.

Comment: So why "&" doesn't work?

Comment: It works as expected. Use `\text{Subject to }` and `\text{Min/Max }`.

Comment: Because you should have 3 `&` for two alignment points.

Comment: There are three alignment points, so 3x2 - 1 `&` per line. You're missing the extra on on the right

Comment: Thanks all of you for your help. I edited the question in accordance with the comments

Comment: Generally, the `align` family of environments alternate right alignment and then left alignment.

Comment: Regarding your edit, we generally prefer that answers get posted as such, so that we can vote on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I propose this simple code, and a slightly different alignment, with `empheq` and `alignedat`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{empheq}
\DeclareMathOperator{\MinMax}{Min/Max}

    \begin{document}
\begin{empheq}[right=\enspace\empheqrbrace]{equation}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
\MinMax f_m (x)&, &\enspace & m=1,2,...,M; \\[1ex]
\text{Subject to}& & & h_k (x) \geq 0, \enspace k=1,2,...,K; \\
                         & & & g_j (x)=0, \enspace j=1,2,...,J; \\
                         & & & x_i^{(L)} \leq x_i \leq x_i^{(U)}, \enspace i=1,2,...,n.
\end{alignedat}
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

[image]